# Loop trough items in view template and access field values?

Tags: views, entities

Drupal 8
name of twig: views-view-grid--places.html

I'm extremely new to Drupal so bare with me and excuse any incorrect lingo.

I created a content type called places and added 2 fields (*body* and *field_location*). *title* is a default for fields.

In my view twig, how do I get those values in my for loop?

```
{% for item in items %}
    <section>
        <div>{{ item.title }}</div>
        <div>{{ item.field_location }}</div>
        <div>{{ item.content }}</div>
    </section>
{% endfor %}
```

This only outputs the body. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Use `{{ dump(item) }}` to see the structure.

Once you have the structure you can reference in a faily regular way: if a sub-item is an array or an object, then it's a dot, if an array with a #, reference as an array eg xxx.yyy['#zzz']